# Python string remove hex codes like in 'president trump\\xe2\\x80\\x99s'

Tags: python, string, hex

I searched a while but couldn't find something helpful.
I try to delete these hex codes in strings in a Paython List, but can't figure out how to do that. They are in string format!
Except from my Data (Trump Twitter fetches):

```
tweets[7]
'rt @ lindseygrahamsc : i support president trump\\xe2\\x80\\x99s desire to reenter the paris accord after the agreement becomes a better deal for america\\xe2\\x80\\xa6'
```

Thank You!

Comment: Do you want to delete the hex codes or are you asking whether they can be converted to ASCII? (Note that those are all numbers greater than 128, so not part of standard ASCII set.)

Comment: it 's difficult to help you as you don't provide details on how you get this string. btw, maybe you should get back to the root of your problem by encoding tweets right as you get them, e.g.  status.text.encode("utf-8")

Comment: Thanks! I just want to delete them and focus on plain text, so some solution in that direction would be great!

Comment: I got a little workaround, quick and dirty:
`' '.join([w for w in new.replace('\\', ' *').split() if not w.startswith('*')])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, it only work to sub string '`\\x**`':

```
import re
tweets = 'rt @ lindseygrahamsc : i support president trump\\xe2\\x80\\x99s desire to reenter the paris accord after the agreement becomes a better deal for america\\xe2\\x80\\xa6'
re.sub(r'(\\x(.){2})', '',tweets)
```

output:

```
'rt @ lindseygrahamsc : i support president trumps desire to reenter the paris accord after the agreement becomes a better deal for america'
```